# Regularization Term using Lambda returning "invalid syntax"

Tags: python, lambda

Trying to write the regularization term for logistic regression in python.

In Octive I used the following code:

```
reg_term = (lambda / (2 * m) * theta_revised' * theta_revised;
```

tried the following code in python;

```
reg_term = (lambda / (2 * m)) * np.transpose(theta_revised).dot(theta_revised);
```

getting a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` with pointer aimed at the "/"

```
#sigmoid function that calculates 1/(1 + e**-x)
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1+ np.exp(-x))

#h is the prediction calculated taking the sigmoid of X * theta
h = sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta));

#need to remove the first theta term for regularization
theta_less = theta[1:size(theta)];
theta_revised = np.append([0],theta_less);

#Calculate the regularization term
#reg_term = (lambda/(2*m)) * (theta_revised' * theta_revised);
reg_term = (lambda / (2 * m)) * np.transpose(theta_revised).dot(theta_revised);
```

Comment: ```lambda``` is a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3.0/reference/lexical_analysis.html#id8) in python (ask yourself why it's rendered blue in above highlighting!). Rename it to ```lambda_``` or something else.

Comment: Before trying machine learning in different language better to learn the basics of that language.

Comment: So where are you *defining* the value for `lambda`?

Answer (score 0):

`lambda` is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords), you can't use it as a general variable name.

Rename the variable; adding a `_` to the name would be an easy work-around:

```
reg_term = (lambda_ / (2 * m)) * np.transpose(theta_revised).dot(theta_revised)
```

Note that you have not defined a value for `lambda_` anywhere, so no you will have a `NameError` exception. Also note that Python expressions do not need to end with `;`, you'd not normally use a semicolon.